# JQuery talking to DJango REST API. Need to return number of pages in response

Tags: jquery, django, pagination, django-rest-framework, serialization

Am new to Django REST framework. I have an application that has a listings page. When page is loaded, JQuery should talk to API and when response received it should display a list of available entertainers, which I need paginated.
I have pagination working but currently have the number of page links hard coded. I need the either the total number of records or the number of pages returned in the response from the API so that I can dynamically build the links in the template
I have tried it a few ways but have not been successful
Firstly by passing in Response from my **views.py** which uses a Class based view

```
if self.request.GET['page'] is not None:
    if self.request.GET['page'] != 'all':
        page = self.request.GET['page']

recordsPerPage = 8
paginator = Paginator(entertainers, recordsPerPage)
total_records = paginator.count
num_pages = paginator.num_pages
entertainers = paginator.page(int(page))

return Response({
   'count': paginator.count,
   'num_pages': paginator.num_pages,
   'results': serialized_data
})
```

This produced an "Internal Server Error"

The other way I tried to do it was to add in a custom field in my **serializers.py** file but it also gave an Internal Server error

```
class EntertainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('record_count')

    def record_count(self, foo):
        return foo.name == "10"

class Meta:
    model = Entertainer
    fields = (...,'my_field')
```

My JQuery is

```
var populateTemplate = function(){
    $('#REST-data').html('');

    var restDataDiv = $('#REST-data');
    for(i=0;i<apiResponseArr.length;i++){
        var card = $('<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 margin-top-1"><a href="/entertainers/profile/'+apiResponseArr[i].id+'"><div class="card h-100"><img class="card-img-top" src="'+apiResponseArr[i].profile_image_url+'" class="img-fluid center-block img-thumbnail" style="max-height:150px;" alt="'+apiResponseArr[i].profile_image_url+'" /><div class="card-body"><h4 class="card-title">'+apiResponseArr[i].title+'</h4><p class="card-text">'+apiResponseArr[i].bio_summary+'</p></div></div></a></div>');

        restDataDiv.append(card);
    }
};

var requestForJsonData = function(description,location,callingFunction, page){
    var host = window.location.hostname;

    // IF RUNNING ON LOCALHOST
    var entertainerAPI = 'http://' + host + ':8000/entertainers/api/listings/?';

    $.getJSON(entertainerAPI,{description: description,location: location, page: page}, function(){
        console.log('success');
    }).done(function( json ) {
        apiResponseArr = json;
        // Check which function called the requestForJsonDat function
        if('refineSearch' == callingFunction || 'initLoad' == callingFunction){
            //  Call to populate the templates with the JSON data
            populateTemplate();
        }
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });

};

var refineSearch = function(menus){
    var description = 'all';
    var location = 'all';
    var page = 'all'
    /*  Build click event for the refine button */
    $('#refine-button').click(function(){
        description = $('#description-select').val();
        location = $('#location-select').val();
        requestForJsonData(description,location,'refineSearch',page);
    });

    $('.listing-pager').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).text();
        description = $('#description-select').val();
        location = $('#location-select').val();
        requestForJsonData(description,location,'refineSearch',page);
    });
};
```

Each of my page links in the template have a class of "listing-pager

```
<a href="#" class="listing-pager">1</a>
<a href="#" class="listing-pager">2</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py add below code

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
  'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

use generic ListAPIView see below example

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class PaginatedListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    paginate_by = 50
```

References:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/
http://djangorestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guide/pagination/